# Disabling gridview refresh when a particular row is selected

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to disable refresh in a GridView when a particular row is selected as it is refreshing the whole page as I have bing map reloaded everytime.

I have tried

```
function showKeyCode(e) 
{
    var keycode = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 116) {
        event.keyCode = 0;
        event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
}
```

or

```
OnClientClick = "javascript:return false;"
```

but it does not help. Can you please guide me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "when a particular row is selected", do you mean you click on a "Select" link in a column or something similar?

I think you should tell more about your GridView to know why there is a page `postback`.

EDIT: Here's a sample (Checkout the ScriptManager and UpdatePanel)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:gridview runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" ID="MyGrid">
            </asp:gridview>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well, the default "Select" `CommandField` will postback. If you prevent the postback, the row won't be selected. Are you trying to stop selecting only a particular row by checking a condition?

Comment: No. I want to be able to select the the required row data, but I want to disable postback, as it refreshes my complete page, which I dont want as it reloads my map which looses the data over it.

Comment: You can put your grid inside an ASP.NET Ajax UpdatePanel, then the whole page won't postback, only the UpdatePanel will refresh.

Comment: hey thanks for this, but is there a default script that I can use for it to work, I get an error "The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page." can you help me in this ?

Comment: @hesh Check my updated answer. I have added an example that shows the ScriptManager and UpdatePanel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4020/discussion-between-hesh-and-guganeshan-t)

Comment: Hey Guganesha, I am unable to do any selections of my grid view, I mean it does not copy to a text box which it used to , how do I edit it?
TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;