# how to stop page refresh on click of gridview row

Tags: c#-2.0

I have scrolling Gridview and when I click on Select link on each row then it populates  detailsview control and refreshes the full page. Could you please advice how to stop page refresh ?

Also, this gridview is in content page rather than Master page.

Gridview code is given below.

```
      <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UniqueID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="UniqueID" Visible="false"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address" />


    </Columns>
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"  />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />


</asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

Thanks & Regards
Care Career

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648217/disabling-gridview-refresh-when-a-particular-row-is-selected and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716169/how-to-stop-whoe-page-refresh-on-click-of-gridview-row and using ajax http://www.ezineasp.net/post/C-Ajax-GridView-Select-in-ASP-Net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can populate the controls or your Data Entry Form without the postback. example RowBoundEvent of Gridview.

Comment: I have used all coding in .aspx pages. Now i have to modify all my code :(

Comment: I am using Gridview control and when I select one row in gridview then it displays other records(all records) in the detailsview control on the same page.Can you please advice how I populate detailsview control on RowBoundEvent?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for you is to use UpdatePane. If you don’t know much about Ajax.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView>
Rest of your code ……..
</asp:GridView>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: It is still refreshing the page . I have used the same code in content page.No luck :(

Comment: you need to place both controls in same updatePanel ( detailsview  and gridview)

Comment: I have put both controls in updatepanel however when I click on select link in Gridview then it takes much time to populate detailsview control.Speed is really very slow. Could you please advice regarding this issue ? Thanks.